# Python+ocaml TCPServer, TIME_WAIT

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ocaml

I'm trying to have an ocaml (client) process communicate with a python (server) process over a TCP socket; they are both pretty simple and just need to send lots of little json messages to each other. But, after a while -- after having made many connections -- the client is no longer able to connect; running `netstat` reveals many connections in a TIME_WAIT state. My hunch is that the problem is with the python server, because netcat also can't connect once it gets into this state. I was wondering if anyone here could take a look at my python server code and tell me if I am doing everything correctly? I'm including the ocaml server for completeness.

​

Here is a minimal working example: the client and server should just exchange ping/pong indefinitely.

```
import socketserver
import json
import codecs
import socket

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass


class CommandHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        k = json.load(codecs.getreader('utf-8')(self.rfile))
        assert k == "ping"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps("pong"), 'ascii'))
        self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.request.close()

socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = ThreadedTCPServer(("localhost", 9119), CommandHandler, False)
server.allow_reuse_address = True
server.server_bind()
server.server_activate()


server.serve_forever()
```

ocaml client:

```
open Core

let send_to_server message =
  let open Yojson.Safe in
  let p = 9119 in
  let h = Unix.Inet_addr.localhost in
  let (ic,oc) = Unix.open_connection (ADDR_INET(h,p)) in
  Yojson.Safe.to_channel oc message;
  Out_channel.flush oc;
  Unix.shutdown ~mode:SHUTDOWN_SEND (Unix.descr_of_out_channel oc);

  let r = Yojson.Safe.from_channel ic in
  Unix.shutdown ~mode:SHUTDOWN_RECEIVE (Unix.descr_of_in_channel ic);
  In_channel.close ic;

  r

let rec stress_test_client countdown =
  let open Yojson.Basic.Util in
  let m = (`String("ping")) in
  assert(send_to_server m = `String("pong"));
  if countdown = 0 then
  (Printf.printf "+";
  Pervasives.flush stdout);
  stress_test_client (if countdown = 0 then 1000 else countdown - 1)
;;


stress_test_client 1000;;
```

For what it's worth, I have many clients running simultaneously, so the server is fielding a ton of connections for hours at a time. Here is what the client eventually outputs:

```
  (Unix.Unix_error "Cannot assign requested address" connect
   "((addr (ADDR_INET 127.0.0.1 9119)))")
```

Here is the output of `netstat` after a few minutes:

```
$ netstat|grep -F 'localhost:9119'|head
tcp        0      0 localhost:51462         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:43853         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:43380         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:57290         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:45057         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:47191         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:37802         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:55206         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:46369         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:55730         localhost:9119          TIME_WAIT
```

...but, repeatedly connecting with netcat seems to work, so it is possible that the bug is in the client:

```
while true; do echo '"ping"'|nc localhost 9119; done
```

does not give any obvious problems.

Comment: You're not closing the output channel `oc`

Comment: Thanks - I tried adding the following line `Out_channel.close oc;` at different points in the code, but I either get errors when I then try to read from `ic` or I then get errors when trying to close `ic` (in both cases it complains `Bad file descriptor`). Closing only `oc` (and not closing `ic`) leads to the original problem (connections work for a while and then I get `Cannot assign requested address`)

Comment: Try closing both `ic` and `oc` *after* you've received the response from the server. Also, calling `shutdown` immediately before `close` is unnecessary, as `close` will do everything that `shutdown` does anyway. (`shutdown` all by itself is only needed for very specialized situations. For what you're doing, no `shutdown` is needed at all - on either side.)

Comment: I seem to need `shutdown` after the client sends the message, or else the server hangs while reading from the socket (which could be a problem with the server!). But, closing `oc` at any point after `shutdown` gives `Bad file descriptor`. Fwiw, if I take my original code and wait a few minutes after it runs into trouble, everything works again -- and I can see that the TIME_WAIT connections vanish after a few minutes.